# Magit: how to do an octopus merge?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I've been working with magit for a few months, and I'm gradually coming to use it to do more and more git actions, but I still haven't figured out how use magit to do an octopus merge. In these cases I still need to open the shell and write out the merge command explicitly, e.g.

```
git merge branchA branchB
```

when I'm checked out on `master`.

How do I specify multiple heads for the merge commit?